# Want to disappear admob banner ad on specific page on webview android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, webview, admob

I have android webview app and integrate on it admob banner ad, the banner ad appear on every page that

user navigate to it , I want the banner ad disappear on this url or any url contain "google url"

i cannot add url of google due to policy of stackoverflow

My main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OSSubscriptionObserver,
        PurchasesUpdatedListener {

    public static boolean HIDE_ADS_FOR_PURCHASE = false;
    public static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 9541;
    public static final String ERROR_DETECTED = "No NFC tag detected!";
    public static final String WRITE_SUCCESS = "Text written to the NFC tag successfully!";
    public static final String WRITE_ERROR = "Error during writing, is the NFC tag close enough to your device?";

    private static final String INDEX_FILE = "file:///android_asset/local-html/index.html";
    private static final String ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = BuildConfig.ONESIGNAL_APP_ID;
    private CustomWebView webView;
    private FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig;
    private Button openLinkButton;
    private WebView mWebviewPop;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private static final int AD_HIDE_DELAY = 60000;
    private NativeAdView nativeAdView;
    private Button closeButton;

    private TemplateView myTemplate;
    private LinearLayout my_template;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences preferencesColor;
    private RelativeLayout mContainer;
    private RelativeLayout windowContainer;

    private View offlineLayout;


    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_QR_SCAN = 1234;

    private AdView mAdView;
    private AdLoader adLoader;
    private LinearLayout facebookBannerContainer;
    private com.facebook.ads.AdView facebookAdView;
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd facebookInterstitialAd;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    public static final int MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 10;
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String deepLinkingURL;
    private BillingClient billingClient;
    int mCount = -2;

    private static final String TAG = ">>>>>>>>>>>";
    private String mCM, mVM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR = 1;
    public String hostpart;
    private boolean disableAdMob = false;
    private String successUrl = "", failUrl = "";
    private FrameLayout adLayout;
    private boolean offlineFileLoaded = false;
    private boolean isNotificationURL = false;
    private boolean extendediap = true;
    public String uuid = "";
    public static Context mContext;
    private String firebaseUserToken = "";

    private boolean isRedirected = false;


    static long TimeStamp = 0;
    static boolean isInBackGround = false;
    private static boolean connectedNow = false;

    // NFC
    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
    private Tag myTag;
    private boolean NFCenabled = false;
    private boolean readModeNFC = false;
    private boolean writeModeNFC = false;
    private String textToWriteNFC = "";
    private boolean SPLASH_SCREEN_ACTIVE = false;
    // Social media login user agents
    public static final String USER_AGENT_GOOGLE = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.101 Mobile Safari/537.36";
    public static final String USER_AGENT_FB = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";

    // Manual Cookie Sync
    private final Handler cookieSyncHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable cookieSyncRunnable;
    private boolean onResumeCalled = false;
    private boolean cookieSynvcOn = false;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContext = this;
        uuid = Settings.System.getString(super.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        preferencesColor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        onResumeCalled = false;

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String ret = settings.getString("disableAdMobDone", "default");

        if (ret == "removed") {
            disableAdMob = true;
        }


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (Config.blackStatusBarText) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
            }
        }
        if (Config.PREVENT_SLEEP) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        } else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (SPLASH_SCREEN_ACTIVATED) {
            SPLASH_SCREEN_ACTIVE = true;
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashScreen.class));


        }

        // Support the cut out background when in landscape mode
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(24, 24, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bitmap.eraseColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this);
        AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(this, "ca-app-pub-1334133657148088/58006001717")
                .forNativeAd(new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNativeAdLoaded(NativeAd nativeAd) {
                        NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
                                NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build();
                        TemplateView template = findViewById(R.id.my_template);
                        template.setStyles(styles);
                        template.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
                    }
                })
                .build();

        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


        verifyStoragePermission(this);


        //        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
//        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
//        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
//            builder.detectFileUriExposure();
//        }
//        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
//                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
//                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//            // Permission is granted
//        }
//        else {
//            //Permission is not granted so you have to request it
//            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
//                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
//                    888);
//        }


        if (NFCenabled) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.NFC) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.NFC},
                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                initNfc();
            }
        }

        if (Config.FIREBASE_PUSH_ENABLED) {
            fetchFCMToken();
        }

        RelativeLayout main = findViewById(R.id.main);
        adLayout = findViewById(R.id.ad_layout);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                .setListener(this)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build();
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {

                    billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP,
                            (billingResult1, purchasesList) -> {

                                Log.i(TAG, "is purchased : " + (purchasesList != null && !purchasesList.isEmpty()));

                                if (billingResult1.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
                                        && purchasesList != null && !purchasesList.isEmpty()) {

                                    boolean productFound = true;
                                    if (productFound) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "purchased " + String.valueOf(true));
                                        HIDE_ADS_FOR_PURCHASE = true;
                                        AlertManager.purchaseState(getApplicationContext(), true);
                                        if (AlertManager.isPurchased(getApplicationContext())) {
                                            HIDE_ADS_FOR_PURCHASE = true;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "purchased " + String.valueOf(false));
                                        HIDE_ADS_FOR_PURCHASE = false;
                                        AlertManager.purchaseState(getApplicationContext(), false);
                                        if (AlertManager.isPurchased(getApplicationContext())) {
                                            HIDE_ADS_FOR_PURCHASE = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "purchased " + String.valueOf(false));
                                    HIDE_ADS_FOR_PURCHASE = false;
                                    AlertManager.purchaseState(getApplicationContext(), false);
                                    if (AlertManager.isPurchased(getApplicationContext())) {
                                        HIDE_ADS_FOR_PURCHASE = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null && (intent.getData().getScheme().equals("http"))) {
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            List<String> pathSegments = data.getPathSegments();
            if (pathSegments.size() > 0) {
                deepLinkingURL = pathSegments.get(0).substring(5);
                String fulldeeplinkingurl = data.getPath().toString();
                fulldeeplinkingurl = fulldeeplinkingurl.replace("/link=", "");
                deepLinkingURL = fulldeeplinkingurl;
            }
        } else if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null && (intent.getData().getScheme().equals("https"))) {
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            List<String> pathSegments = data.getPathSegments();
            if (pathSegments.size() > 0) {
                deepLinkingURL = pathSegments.get(0).substring(5);
                String fulldeeplinkingurl = data.getPath().toString();
                fulldeeplinkingurl = fulldeeplinkingurl.replace("/link=", "");
                deepLinkingURL = fulldeeplinkingurl;
            }
        }

        if (intent != null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String URL = null;
            if (extras != null) {
                URL = extras.getString("ONESIGNAL_URL");
            }
            if (URL != null && !URL.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                isNotificationURL = true;
                deepLinkingURL = URL;
            } else isNotificationURL = false;
        }


        final String myOSurl = Config.PURCHASECODE;

        if (Config.PUSH_ENABLED) {
            OneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver(this);
            OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler(
                    new OneSignal.OSNotificationOpenedHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {

                            String actionId = result.getAction().getActionId();

                            String title = result.getNotification().getTitle();
                            Log.e("RESULTTITLE", title);


                            JSONObject data = result.getNotification().getAdditionalData();
                            String launchUrl = result.getNotification().getLaunchURL();
                            String urlString = null;
                            if (data != null && data.has("url")) {
                                try {
                                    urlString = data.getString("url");
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            // Log.e("OneSignal_Deeplinking", urlString); //Deeplinking URL of OneSignal (url key-value pair)

                            if (urlString != null) {
                                handleURl(urlString);
                            } else {
                                if (launchUrl != null) {
                                    openInExternalBrowser(launchUrl);
                                }

                            }


                            long diffseconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - TimeStamp);

                            if (isInBackGround && diffseconds >= 3)
                                foreground(launchUrl, urlString);


                        }
                    });
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            AlertManager.appLaunched(this);
        }

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adViewSmartBanner);
        if (Config.USE_FACEBOOK_ADS) {
            Log.e(TAG, "attempting to create ad");
            facebookAdView = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(this,
                    getString(R.string.facebook_banner_footer),
                    AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
        }

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();


        if (Config.SHOW_BANNER_AD && !disableAdMob) {
            if (Config.USE_FACEBOOK_ADS) {
                adLayout.removeAllViews();
                adLayout.addView(facebookAdView);
                adLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                facebookAdView.loadAd();
            } else {
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
                adLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        if (!HIDE_ADS_FOR_PURCHASE) {
                            mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            adLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            adLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onAdOpened() {
                        if (!HIDE_ADS_FOR_PURCHASE) {
                            mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            adLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            adLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (!HIDE_ADS_FOR_PURCHASE) {
            if (Config.USE_FACEBOOK_ADS) {
                facebookInterstitialAd = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(this, getString(R.string.facebook_interstitial_full_screen));
                com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdListener interstitialAdListener = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInterstitialDisplayed(com.facebook.ads.Ad ad) {
                        // Interstitial ad displayed callback
                        Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad displayed.");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInterstitialDismissed(com.facebook.ads.Ad ad) {
                        // Interstitial dismissed callback
                        Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad dismissed.");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(com.facebook.ads.Ad ad, com.facebook.ads.AdError adError) {
                        // Ad error callback
                        Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad failed to load: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(com.facebook.ads.Ad ad) {
                        // Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
                        Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClicked(com.facebook.ads.Ad ad) {
                        // Ad clicked callback
                        Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad clicked!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoggingImpression(com.facebook.ads.Ad ad) {
                        // Ad impression logged callback
                        Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad impression logged!");
                    }
                };

                // For auto play video ads, it's recommended to load the ad
                // at least 30 seconds before it is shown
                facebookInterstitialAd.loadAd(
                        facebookInterstitialAd.buildLoadAdConfig()
                                .withAdListener(interstitialAdListener)
                                .build());
            }
        }

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        TemplateView my_template = findViewById(R.id.my_template);

        closeButton = findViewById(R.id.closeButton);

        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                my_template.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                closeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback loadCallback = new AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
            @Override


            public void onAdLoaded(AppOpenAd ad) {
                ad.show(MainActivity.this);
            }
        };
        AppOpenAd.load(
                this,
                "ca-app-pub-1334133657148088/282901800682",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build(),
                AppOpenAd.APP_OPEN_AD_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT,
                loadCallback
        );

        AdView adViewSmartBanner = findViewById(R.id.adViewSmartBanner);
        AdRequest adrequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adViewSmartBanner.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Delay showing the banner ad for 60 seconds


        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
        FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(30)
                .build();
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);

        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults);


        Task<Void> fetchTask = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch();
        fetchTask.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activate();
                    String webViewUrl = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("webview_url");
                    String buttonUrl = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("button_url");


                    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
                    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
                    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                    webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);

                    Button openLinkButton = findViewById(R.id.openLinkButton);
                    openLinkButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                        webView.loadUrl(buttonUrl);
                    });
                } else {
                }
            }
        });


        mContainer = findViewById(R.id.web_container);
        windowContainer = findViewById(R.id.window_container);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
        webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webView.setGestureDetector(new GestureDetector(new CustomeGestureDetector()));


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        if (!ENABLE__PULL_REFRESH) {
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

        }

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        if (ENABLE__PULL_REFRESH) {
                            webView.reload();

                        }
                        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    }
                }
        );

        offlineLayout = findViewById(R.id.offline_layout);
        setOfflineScreenBackgroundColor();

        this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.launchLoadingSignBackground));
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        final Button tryAgainButton = findViewById(R.id.try_again_button);
        tryAgainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("Try again!");
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loadMainUrl();
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new AdvanceWebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        Context appContext = this;

        // Collect the App Name to use as the title for Javascript Dialogs
        final String appName;
        String appName1;
        try {
            appName1 = appContext.getApplicationInfo().loadLabel(appContext.getPackageManager()).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If unsuccessful in collecting the app name, set the name to the page title.
            appName1 = webView.getTitle();
        }
        appName = appName1;

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new AdvanceWebChromeClient() {

            // Functions to support alert(), confirm() and prompt() Javascript Dialogs

            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).
                        setTitle(appName).
                        setMessage(message).
                        setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //do nothing
                            }
                        }).create();
                dialog.show();
                result.confirm();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
                AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                        .setTitle(appName)
                        .setMessage(message)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                result.confirm();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                result.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                b.show();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message, String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result) {
                final EditText input = new EditText(appContext);
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                input.setText(defaultValue);
                new AlertDialog.Builder(appContext)
                        .setTitle(appName)
                        .setView(input)
                        .setMessage(message)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                result.confirm(input.getText().toString());
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                result.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
                return true;
            }
        });


        webView.setDownloadListener((url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength) -> {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        });

        registerForContextMenu(webView);

        final WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        if (Config.CLEAR_CACHE_ON_STARTUP) {
            //webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
            webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        } else {
            //webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
        }
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        //webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        //webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW)
```

try to disappear banner on the url "www.google.com"